# Could I use excel to update data on a table?

Tags: database, excel, sql-update

After the financial department calculate our sales budget, our salesman must to approve or change that budget.

We are thinking to create an excel sheet to help them.

The idea is to read the data from a table and show it on a spreadsheet and let the salesman change some amounts, after that the excel must update a table with the changes.

Is that possible? how could be the approach?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be two buttons:

1) to retrieve data from DB :

```
Dim qt As QueryTable
sqlstring1 = "SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY ProductID"
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=getConnectionStr, Destination:=Range("A1"), sql:=sqlstring1)

Private Function getConnectionStr2()
getConnectionStr2 = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};" & _
                   "DATABASE=dbname;" & _
                   "SERVER=100.100.100.100;" & _
                   "UID=username;" & _
                   "PWD=userpassword;"
End Function
```

2) should loop throw values and create a dynamic Update script.